# insert data into SQLite

Tags: android

I am stuck to fix the error when I am insert data into the database  here is my code:

```
package com.example.pr;

import android.R.integer;
import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class addcustomer extends Activity {
    private int customer_id;
    private string name;
    private int passportNo;
    private int ID;
    private string addr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_cusact);

        EditText txtName =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText CusID =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        EditText Pass =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        EditText Addr =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);

        final int CusID1;
        final int pass1;
        Button btnAddNewcustomer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final String txtname1=txtName.getText().toString();
        if(CusID.getText().toString()!="")
        CusID1=Integer.parseInt(CusID.getText().toString());
        else
        CusID1=0;

        if(Pass.getText().toString()!="")
        pass1=Integer.parseInt(Pass.getText().toString());
        else 
            pass1=0;
        final String Addr1=Addr.getText().toString();

        btnAddNewcustomer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            insertData(txtname1,CusID1,pass1,Addr1);

            Toast.makeText(addcustomer.this,"added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void insertData(String name,int CUSID,int PASSN, String ADDRN) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AndroidDbHelper helper = new AndroidDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

        content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
        content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME2, CUSID);
        content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME3, PASSN);
        content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME4, ADDRN);

        database.insert(AndroidDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, content);


    }   

}

        private void insertData(String name,int CUSID,int PASSN, String ADDRN) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            AndroidDbHelper helper = new AndroidDbHelper(this);
            SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues content = new ContentValues();

            content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME, name);
            content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME2, CUSID);
            content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME3, PASSN);
            content.put(AndroidDbHelper.COLUMN_NAME4, ADDRN);

            database.insert(AndroidDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, content);
        }   
    }
```

here is database helper class that will used to create the database
it seems work fine

```
package com.example.pr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class AndroidDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "StudentData";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "student";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME= "NAME";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME2= "CUSTOMERID";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME3= "PASSPORT";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME4= "ADDR";

    public AndroidDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CreateTable = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME + "(" +"ID INTEGER primary key AUTOINCREMENT,"
                   + "NAME VARCAR NOT NULL,"
                    + "CUSTOMERID INTEGER,"
                   + "PASSPORT INT,"
                   + "ADDR VARCHAR NOT NULL"+");";
        db.execSQL(CreateTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " +TABLE_NAME );       
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

the app is crashed!

here is my log:

```
04-11 14:15:36.860: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 53 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:15:37.200: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 395 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:15:37.330: D/gralloc_goldfish(1171): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-11 14:15:37.870: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 483 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:30.030: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 225 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:31.450: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:32.410: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 281 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:34.670: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 150 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:36.050: I/Choreographer(1171): Skipped 256 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:18:39.330: D/AndroidRuntime(1171): Shutting down VM
04-11 14:18:39.330: W/dalvikvm(1171): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4adbb90)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): Process: com.example.pr, PID: 1171
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pr/com.example.pr.addcustomer}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at com.example.pr.addcustomer.onCreate(addcustomer.java:63)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
04-11 14:18:39.560: E/AndroidRuntime(1171):     ... 11 more
04-11 14:18:40.160: D/dalvikvm(1171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 105K, 6% free 3078K/3252K, paused 527ms, total 540ms
04-11 14:18:45.690: I/Process(1171): Sending signal. PID: 1171 SIG: 9
04-11 14:24:50.490: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:50.780: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 354 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:50.810: D/gralloc_goldfish(1226): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-11 14:24:51.030: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:54.700: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 240 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:56.140: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 179 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:56.970: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 195 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:24:58.700: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:25:00.470: I/Choreographer(1226): Skipped 336 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-11 14:25:04.310: D/AndroidRuntime(1226): Shutting down VM
04-11 14:25:04.310: W/dalvikvm(1226): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4adbb90)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226): Process: com.example.pr, PID: 1226
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pr/com.example.pr.addcustomer}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226): Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at com.example.pr.addcustomer.onCreate(addcustomer.java:63)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
04-11 14:25:04.440: E/AndroidRuntime(1226):     ... 11 more
04-11 14:25:05.040: D/dalvikvm(1226): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 107K, 6% free 3077K/3252K, paused 576ms, total 588ms
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the crash

Comment: it give unfortunately the app is stopped when i run this !

Comment: have a look at my answer please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote `"CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME` - it would be `CREATE TABLEStudentData`. You should add space after `TABLE` word.

Comment: i did but the app still crash

Comment: You are trying to parse empty string as Integer. Before call `ParseInt` check if EditText not empty else set int value as 0.

Comment: if(CusID.getText().toString()!="")
       CusID1=Integer.parseInt(CusID.getText().toString());
         else
          CusID1=0;
         
         
         if(Pass.getText().toString()!="")
         
      pass1=Integer.parseInt(Pass.getText().toString());
         else pass1=0;

Comment: i did this but still the same crash !!

Comment: You are getting values in `onCreate` method - all the views are empty. You should call `getText` methods inside `View.OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate(), you are calling

```
int CusID1=Integer.parseInt(CusID.getText().toString());
/////
int pass1=Integer.parseInt(Pass.getText().toString());`
```

but till now there is no data neither `CusID` nor `Pass`, thats why you are getting `NumberFormatException`

Comment: what is the solution in this case!!